# Como puedo asignar la variable Js a mi ruta en Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

Buenas noches necesito insertar la variable "data" que traigo en la función, y asignarla a la ruta

```
                      "render" : function ( data, type, row, meta )
                      {

                          var url = "{{ route('usuarios.edit', Crypt::encrypt(temp)) }}";

                          url = url.replace(temp, data);

                          return "<a type=\"button\" href=\""+url+"\" class=\"btn btn-dark btn-sm\"><i class=\"bi bi-gear\"></i></a>"

                      }
                  },
```

Pero no dice que la variable (temp) es indefinida

Comment: Que es `temp` cuando haces `Crypt::encrypt(temp)`? Una constante PHP?

Comment: También sería útil que muestres cómo defines la ruta en laravel, que aclares si ese código está en una plantilla blade, y si el error es de php o de javascript

Comment: Me gustaría saber porqué mezclas PHP con JavaScript como si fueran la misma cosa. Ambos se ejecutan en entornos totalmente diferentes. ¿Qué hace JavaScript manejado rutas de Laravel o cómo pretendes realizar operaciones en Laravel usando variables de Javascript?